Generate a reference number for Google Form
I do not have experience with coding. I was just hoping to have a reference number generated for every google form submission and have it tracked on the response sheet.
I was able to accomplish this with 1 problem. The reference number that is appearing on the form confirmation page is the previous reference number. Hoping to get solutions from here
// Helper function to store the reference number and return the confirmation message
function storeReferenceNumberAndReturnMessage(e) {
// Generate a reference number
var referenceNumber = generateReferenceNumber();

// Get the Google Sheet to store the reference numbers (optional)
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses");
if (sheet) {
// Append the reference number to the form responses
var responses = e.values;
responses.push(referenceNumber);
sheet.appendRow(responses);
}

// Return the confirmation message with the new reference number
return "Thank you for your submission. Your reference number is: " + referenceNumber;
}

// Function to generate a reference number
function generateReferenceNumber() {
var randomChars = '';
var possibleChars = '0123456789';
for (var i = 0; i \< 4; i++) {
randomChars += possibleChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() \* possibleChars.length));
}
return 'INQ' + randomChars;
}

// This function is triggered every time a form is submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var confirmationMessage = storeReferenceNumberAndReturnMessage(e);

// Update the form confirmation message
var form = FormApp.openById('FormID');
form.setConfirmationMessage(confirmationMessage);
}


You want to show the form respondent a reference number generated on the form submission. Unfortunately, this is not possible with Google Forms.
Instead, if you collect the respondent's email, you might email the respondent using the generated reference number.

Thanks! I appreciate letting me know of that this early. I would've spent more time trying to make it work with close to 0 experience with scripts.
